# Software to view BLOB data for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to view and modify BLOB data in a Windows Explorer like interface. Is there software for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what you need:

http://soft.udm4.com/Programming/viewMore.html